# How can I make my jQuery code work for dynamically loaded HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".wrapper1").scroll(function () {
            $(".wrapper2").scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
        });
        $(".wrapper2").scroll(function () {
            $(".wrapper1").scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
        });
    });
</script>
```

But my HTML is dynamic and added later. Is there a way that I can use this code outside of the dynamically added HTML so that it works after the HTML is loaded ?

Comment: Did any of the people who marked this as duplicate check to see if it works with the scroll event :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can use event delegation. Use

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.wrapper1', function () {
```

instead of

```
$(".wrapper1").scroll(function () {
```

and similarly for all the dynamically loaded elements.

More [info here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with the scroll event.

Comment: Ok.. can you please create a fiddle and post the link here ?

Comment: Have you tried using `window` instead of `document`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`.on()` property](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate dynamically created elements.